# Multistep From and one Submit button

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a multi-step form in angular **[like this](http://scotch.io/demos/angular-multi-step-form#/form/profile)**, how can I add save button for all steps ?

Is it possible ?
 I mean when user is in `form 1` only save data from `'form 1'`

Comment: Store the current form (page) in $rootScope.current_form_step, and use standard submit buttons on each form. intercept submit(), and use some kind of tagging on your inputs/checkboxes/etc. to have the "belong" to the step they've been submitted from.

Comment: is that possible to show me on jsfiddle or plunk ?

Comment: @Bonatoc here is the plunker:http://plnkr.co/edit/wFZAoy4i6izxfO5AAJJn?p=preview

Comment: <form>, not <from> ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use nested ng-form objects, but have an ng-submit only in the outer form, like this:

```
<ng-form name="master" ng-submit="doStuff()">
    <ng-form name="step1"> ... </ng-form>
    <ng-form name="step2"> ... </ng-form>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</ng-form>
```

Or you could skip the inner ng-forms if you don't need specific validation and just use plain form and divs to mimic the multi-form behavior.

Comment: why should i use ng-form ? i have 3 forms with ui-router and i think if i use ng-if i can't wizard form !!! am i right ?

Comment: ng-if have nothing to do with it. You want to use ng-form because you can't do nested form in plain html - it's not valid. So angular team came up with ng-form. The ng-form allows you to apply validation logic to each stage independently (among other things). If you don't need that then you don't need to use ng-form.

Comment: ng-form seems to be the way. Since the example you provided uses ui-router, you can also know which state (route) is the current when you click on submit.

Comment: thx for your explanation but i didn't get you completely.  
here is the question ? where should i store or how can i detect which form i'm using on ?

Comment: the route state display one step back, for example when user in state 2,it shows step 1